# Не работает команда clear

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="/")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@commands.command( pass_context=True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(stx, amount: int):
    await stx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
client.run('MTEwMTU2NjMzMTI1MTMzNTI2OA.GxAWfm.OyXrZzqjcBmVJegbl5fqnTyRonjMpyYajEHyDo')
```

Ошибки нет, но когда пишу команду ничего происходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как написано в API Discord, то команды, которые были созданы декоратором `@commands.Command()` необходимо регистрировать с помощью `discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_command(command_here)`